# Webpack 5 using UMD dependencies instead of ESM after upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm upgrading a huge angular application to Webpack 5 (coming from v4. No ng-cli). In the previous version, webpack was using the `esm` versions of dependencies, and now it is using the `UMD` version.

Since it is using the UMD version, it fails with following error:

```
Error: Error on worker #1: Error: Failed to find exported name of node (MyComponentHere = /** @class */ (function () {...
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "typings",
            "node_modules/@types/"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
        }
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "**/*.ngfactory.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableIvy": false,
    }
}
```